# Mindmap changing layout

Tags: mind-mapping, freemind

Perhaps I am asking something that is counter-intuitive to the concept of a mind map. But I find almost all standard layout options inadequate.

1. For example, if I had only one node that had three children it automatically assumes that one child will sit on the left and the other two will sit on the right. I would like all three nodes to sit on the right (depending on the case)
2. It also assumes all maps originate from center and expand outwards. I may be wired wrong but some of my mindmaps move sequentially from left to right or top to bottom.

Question: Using free tools like FreeMind can I actually create something like this i.e, does any tool have the ability to position/layout nodes as I see fit (almost like eclipse GMF maybe)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freemind lets you do this pretty easily.

To move a node from the left to the right side, simply select it and press Ctrl+Right arrow.

To add nodes only on the right side, select an existing node on that side and press enter. From here on, all children will continue to be added on the right side of their parent.

Comment: The Control -> right arrow does not work for me. When I do it just shows me an empty mind map file

Comment: But the other solution to hit Enter on the first sibling works.